# Guessable oauth client id and phishing

Tags: phishing, oauth

OAuth manual advises that the client ID should not be easily guessable to decrease phishing attacks. https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/
Is it still the case when PKCE is used and auth server redirects only to allowed urls?
In what cases I might need to change client id for existing app?